# curl: (18) transfer closed with 804285 bytes remaining to read

Tags: ubuntu, curl, installation, rvm

***while i was trying to install rvm using the command ::(I am Using UBUNTU 12.04 LTS)***

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s
```

**when i try the same command as simple user i am getting error like**

```
abhay@Abhay:~/Downloads$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io |sudo bash -s
curl: (1) Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

**this is the two paths where my curl is installed**

```
abhay@Abhay:~$ which -a curl
/home/abhay/bin/curl
/usr/local/bin/curl
```

**This is the error i am still getting**

```
root@Abhay:/home/abhay# curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0     33      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--    61
100 13774  100 13774    0     0   1271      0  0:00:10  0:00:10 --:--:--  3214
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   124  100   124    0     0     37      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--    60
 27 1079k   27  294k    0     0   5853      0  0:03:08  0:00:51  0:02:17  8245
curl: (18) transfer closed with 804285 bytes remaining to read

Could not download 'https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz'.
  curl returned status '18'.
```

**And also this**

```
root@Abhay:/home/abhay# \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby --autolibs=enable --auto-dotfiles
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0     42      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:--    70
100 13774  100 13774    0     0   1663      0  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:--  4770
Turning on auto dotfiles mode.
Please read and follow further instructions.
Press ENTER to continue.
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   124  100   124    0     0     42      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--    75
  8 1079k    8 98109    0     0   3745      0  0:04:55  0:00:26  0:04:29  7132

Curl returned 141 - it is result of a segfault which means it's Curls fault.
Try again and if it crashes more than a couple of times you either need to
reinstall Curl or consult with your distribution manual and contact support.
```

Comment: This is what you should do: Re-post your question on [serverFault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: Looks like you have two different versions of curl installed. To find out where they reside, use `which curl` under both accounts (root and simple user). Then you can remove one of them or reconcile the PATH variables of both accounts so they use the same curl.

Comment: @MikeW : looks more like a [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) question to me, I'm not sure.

Comment: @MiklosAubert yes, i know in which directory the both version resides and even i have tried to remove curl but its not working for me (apt-get remove --purge curl) ..after this command still i can see the curl version installed in my system,

Comment: @MiklosAubert so after this what shall i do?

Comment: @MiklosAubert Possibly - but whichever it is, it's not StackOverflow.

Comment: @MiklosAubert Can you tell how to remove or reconcile the PATH variables of both accounts.

Comment: @MikeW i have posted the same in serverfault . thanks

Comment: the first warning is fixed https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/commit/12f2460e9fc82b3e6e183fd6581ac223adcf17de - as for curl problems, you can see all installation paths with: `which -a curl`

Comment: @mpapis thank you for first solution..but can you please tell me what should i do after knowing all paths..

Comment: so first - show them to us, I have a feeling that you can get rid easily of the broken curl

Comment: @mpapis i have added it to this post..please look at it..thanks

Comment: @mpapis Please suggest me something.from past two days i have been searching for the solution..and it will be very kind of you if you could explain me something that you have posted previously about first problem..i didn't really get it..how is that related to the error i am getting while install rvm?? i really need some help

Comment: @mpapis please look at this..this is what i am getting when tried again..i have posted the error at the bottom of this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system seems broken, RVM is tested for installation with ubuntu both when building binary rubies and for http://travis-ci.org

I recommend you remove this system and start with fresh installation without any customizations.

Comment: I forgot to accept this advice as an Answer..trust me after this I did re-installation and bang!..everything worked exactly..thanks a lot..and one more thing you are doing great work "rvm". thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `/home/abhay/bin/curl` from PATH:

```
function remove_from_path()
{
  if
    [[ -n "$1" ]]
  then
    export PATH
    PATH=":${PATH}:"
    PATH="${PATH//:$1:/:}"
    PATH="${PATH//::/:}"
    PATH="${PATH#:}"
    PATH="${PATH%:}"
  fi
}
remove_from_path /home/abhay/bin
```

Comment: ok correct me if i am wrong ..is this the PATH from env. variable you are asking me to remove? i have removed it from ~/.profile is it correct ? ..and what shall i do next?

Comment: i have removed /home/abhay/bin/curl from PATH..now shall i try again to install using curl commmand?

Comment: Sorry for such stupid question but i thought may be there is something else you wanted me to do after this.. that is why i asked you.
i'll let you know after its done ..thank you in advance.

Comment: please look at this..this is what i am getting when tried again..i have posted the error at the bottom of the original post
 ** curl: (18) transfer closed with 804285 bytes remaining to read **